If $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$ and $f<0$ for $x>0$, then $f$ is decreasing in some neighbourhood of $0$
I am trying to prove a statement where it would be useful to make use of the fact (if it is a fact) that

If $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$ and $f<0$  for $x>0$, then $f$ is decreasing in some right-neighbourhood of $0$

Is this statement actually true? I am trying to think of counterexamples but I can't come up with any, though the proof alludes me. If this is actually true, I'm not looking for a complete solution, but any helpful hints to prove it myself

in the spirit of not giving the solution - what sorts of counterexamples in analysis do you know about?

Hint: think about the standard examples of functions that oscillate rapidly as $x\to 0$, and try to modify one so that it's negative and continuous at $0$.

@CalvinKhor That is a rather broad question. I haven't done any real analysis formally but am going through Spivak's Calculus which has some elements of it. If there were a counterexample, I'd think it involves some kind of infinite oscillation with vanishing amplitude near 0, but the fact that $f$ needs to be negative makes it difficult to come up with one

Try plotting $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ in Desmos or something similar and see if you can come up with a way to modify it so it fits your criteria

you can add one of those infinite oscillation + vanishing amp functions to another function to control the 'size in the large'

I have managed to come up with $x(\sin(x)-x-1)$. This fits the criteria I think. Thank you. Should I delete this question, considering it has been sufficiently answered by the comments ?

You can write an answer even to your own question. But this function is an example of a function satisfying the statement. I think you meant $\sin(1/x)$

tl; dr More is true: Under the stated hypotheses we cannot even deduce $f$ is monotone on some interval, i.e., $f$ might be nowhere monotone, or non-monotone on every interval.
Here is an explicit recursive construction. We can arrange that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) < 0$ for all positive (or all non-zero) real $x$. (The details below were written seven years ago for a question that has been deleted from the site—not just deleted by the OP. The images happily did still exist.)

Fix an arbitrary interval $[a, b]$, and let $f_{0}$ be an arbitrary non-constant affine function on $[a, b]$.
Inductively, if $f_{n}$ is a piecewise-affine function on $[a, b]$ (not constant on every interval), obtain $f_{n+1}$ by performing the following construction on each affine segment of the graph:
Let $(a_{1}, b_{1})$ and $(a_{2}, b_{2})$ be arbitrary points not lying on a horizontal or vertical line. Replace the (black) segment from $(a_{1}, b_{1})$ to $(a_{2}, b_{2})$ with the (blue) three-segment zig-zag path having vertices
$$
(a_{1}, b_{1}),\qquad
\bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}(a_{1} + 2a_{2}), \tfrac{1}{3}(2b_{1} + b_{2})\bigr),\qquad
\bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}(2a_{1} + a_{2}), \tfrac{1}{3}(b_{1} + 2b_{2})\bigr),\qquad
(a_{2}, b_{2}).
$$

It's easy to see:

The sequence $(f_{n})$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $f$ on $[a, b]$.


If $n$ and $k$ are non-negative integers, the functions $f_{n}$ and $f_{n+k}$ (and therefore $f_{n}$ and $f$) agree at every "$3$-adic point", i.e., every point of the form $a + \frac{m}{3^{n}}(b - a)$ with $0 \leq m \leq 3^{n}$. (Geometrically, the recursive construction does not change the values at the endpoints of each "affine segment".)

For each $n \geq 0$, and for $0 \leq m < 3^{n}$, the function $f_{n+1}$ (and therefore $f$ itself) is not monotone on $\bigl[a + \frac{m}{3^{n}}(b - a), a + \frac{m+1}{3^{n}}(b - a)\bigr]$.
Every open subinterval of $[a, b]$ contains some interval of this form.



Through helpful comments from Calvin Khor, whpowerll967 and user1149748, I have managed to come up with the following counterexample: $$f(x)=\cases{0\text{ if $x=0$}\\x(\sin(1/x)-1-x)\text{ otherwise}}$$
Clearly, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f=0=f(0)$ so $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty).$ For $x>0$, $\sin(1/x)-1-x\le-x<0\implies f<0$ , and $f$ is not decreasing in any neighbourhood of $0$ as can be seen from the following plot:

EDIT
By a comment from Jiagmath, $$f(x)=\cases{0\text{ if $x=0$}\\x(\sin(1/x)-2)\text{ otherwise}}$$
is a much simpler counterexample. Moreover, this can be modified to $$f(x)=\cases{0\text{ if $x=0$}\\x^2(\sin(1/x)-2)\text{ otherwise}}$$
which is not only continuous but also differentiable on $[0,\infty)$: 

A little simpler: $$x(\sin(1/x)-2)$$

Be sure to accept your answer so the question can be marked as closed

@jjagmath Yes, my bad. That is indeed much better
